# При смене прокси в браузере fiddler перестает перехватывать трафик

Tags: proxy, fiddler

Когда я указываю прокси в браузере, то при посещении любых сайтов fiddler не перехватывет трафик.

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да ну?

Answer (score 3):

Ну вообще-то это нормально.

Фиддер выставляет себя прокси-сервером и перехватывает все программы, которые используют его как прокси-сервер. Соответственно, если ты говоришь какой-то программе использовать другой прокси, то она его и использует вместо фиддера.

Для полного перехвата трафика надо использовать какой-то перехватчик сетевого уровня, например, [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/).